# Google Chrome working incredibly slow

Tags: google-chrome, performance, browser, google-chrome-extensions, lag

So recently I have received a new laptop for work.

It's pretty decent, i5 with 4GB of ram and hybrid SSD hard drive. Google Chrome was always my default browser and it works painfully slow here, I can start typing, finish a sentence and it doesn't even display the first phrase yet. Whenever I inspect element or look up the website source, I can make a coffee in the meantime. No other browser has this problem (Firefox, Opera, IE, Safari). I'm working (trying to work) on the latest version of Chrome.

What can I do to check what can be the cause of this?

Comment: Can you monitor CPU and Disk usage when this happens?

Comment: Well, I know how to monitor CPU usage - it gets up to 50% CPU usage. The weird thing is - it works faster on a outdated desktop that noone uses, so I guess configuration would be the issue here. Is there a way to check if a certain Google Chrome Extension could cause this beyond "turn one off, check, turn next off"?

Comment: You don't even know whether it's an extension problem. Run chrome executable with `--disable-extensions` parameter, or disable all manually.

Comment: If it happens to be an extension problem you don't have to turn on and off one by one, you can perform a binary search (turn half off, then half of half and so on...)

Comment: Well, I just did the binary search (great idea btw), reverted to all previous extensions and it works normally now. I still have no clue what could cause that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple

1. Uninstall and Reinstall Chrome - if that doesn't fix it
2. Optimize your computer

i use the following process

go to msconfig utility (only if you know how to do this) and uncheck all unnecessary 
startup items from the list if you unsure, leave them checked
don't touch anything that has system32 in the file path

then remove all Unused Programs from Add/Remove Programs

then, and only then  Get Auslogics Boostpeed, and do that
Remember to Clean first then optimize,  Not in any random order
Auslogics is a very good program, but it's not free, it's not expensive either

i then, as ongoing maintenance, Use Koshyjohn Diskmax,

those 2 combined Prove to be very very helpful, they increase the speed of any PC that i have worked on since XP by about 70% or so

if you don't want to buy Boostspeed, Just use Diskmax then,  it won't be as good of a clean
but it will help

You will not get the Computer Tweaks Benefit out of it
but.. if you Use Auslogics for the trial period, you will, but you won't be able to Clean and Optmiize your registry

in your case, though, i think You need to Tweak your computer, do that and let me know how you went,

the software is safe, if you need advice on any of the steps i'm here to help

that should work for you

after all that, There would be absolutely no reason Why Chrome on it's own would lag

let me know how go

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have admin rights on this laptop, so basically the only thing I can do was changing the internal Chrome settings and extensions. On my private machine I would do all of the above :( Thanks for the tips tough!

Comment: Oh,OK, in that case, Contact Your system administrator and tell them to read this post, Have i answered you question ?

Comment: I tried, they shrugged me off, said it's a Chrome issue -_-